# I am trying to solve ODE using NDSolve mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I will upload my code again after correcting Mista

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Your post tells us nothing about how long you have used Mathematica, the actual problem or  your code. It is hard to process it further. Kindly post a concrete minimal example as Mathematica code (not images) so that respondents can paste it to their notebook sessions and study/resolve the challenges you face. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you syed. I have been using mathematical for over two years, I have used the NDSolve for time backward trajectory plotting but never faced problem but this particular ODE is giving me problem. I will post my mathematical code here soon.

Comment: I have added my mathematica code, please have a look, thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing definitions of your parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question again. you can take C1 100.

Comment: Your code produces a number of errors, the first of which is that `TotalGridPoints` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to edit the code properly. I used paralleltable to get solutions for different initial conditions, we can take total gridpoint anything as I have explicitly mentioned the one initial condition (i.e. pi/4 , pi/4, 0).

Answer (score 1):

NDSolve can only solve purely numerical equations.

With

```
 h=Hold[NDsolve[ .....]];
```

you can encapsulate the input and check for non numerical symbols

```
Cases[h, _Symbol, \[Infinity]] // Union

Out:={C1, \[Pi], t, \[Kappa], \[Lambda]}
```

you find  at least C1, kappa and lambda as symbols.  You have to provide numerical values